# Fullcalendar.io Custom View for Week in two rows

Tags: fullcalendar

I am trying to change the the view for Week. But I am not doing any progress.
What I want is the "dayGridWeek", but formatted like this:

[image: 2 Rows for a week]

Question is:

a) Can I do this somehow without creating a custom view?

b) If I need to create a custom view, can someone please provide me an good example of a custom view with some content in it?

Thank you!

Comment: a) No...this is exactly what custom views are intended for. b) Just take a look at the existing views in the fullCalendar source code.